# code not working - .indexOf not a function

Tags: for-loop, indexof

I was doing some exercises on FreeCodeCamp to learn how to use indexOf. I then reproduced the same exercise with some slight variation, but I got stuck at indexOf, not recognized as a function.

I get this error from console.

```
mySecondArray[i].indexOf is not a function
```

Could someone please help me in understanding why this is happening and what I should take care of next time?

Thank you

```
let mySecondArray = [1,2];
mySecondArray.push([1,2], [2,3], [10,20])
console.log(mySecondArray);

function myThirdArray(mySecondArray, elem) {
  let myThirdArray = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < mySecondArray.length; i++) {
    if(mySecondArray[i].indexOf(elem)==-1) {
    myThirdArray.push(mySecondArray[i]);  
    };
  };
  return myThirdArray; 
} 

console.log(myThirdArray(mySecondArray,2));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ever get a `.methodName is not a function` error on a variable, it usually means the data type isn't what you think it is - in this case `mySecondArray[i]` must not (always) be an array – so it has no `.indexOf` method.

The easiest way to debug this is usually to just `console.log(mySecondArray)` and notice the inconsistency (although it looks like you're already doing that.)

---

In this case, you're doing:

```
let mySecondArray = [1,2];
mySecondArray.push([1,2], [2,3], [10,20])
```

So `mySecondArray` is `[1, 2, [1,2], [2,3], [10,20]]`, meaning you're trying to `.indexOf` on `1`.

If you meant to make the original array also be a nested array, you'd want:

```
let mySecondArray = [[1,2]]; // now it's an array, with `[1,2]` as its first element.
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
    for(let i = 0; i < mySecondArray.length; i++)

please try mySecondArray.length-1 in for loop condition

```
 for(let i = 0; i < mySecondArray.length-1; i++)
```

Hope this helps thank you